# sscanf iterative loop for float numbers

Tags: c, scanf

I need to convert recursively char[] into float variable. My code is as follows:

```
while(1)
{
    //take char[] str as input
    sscanf(str,"%f",&n);
    //printf n
}
```

The program works well for positive numbers. But if we give negative numbers initially
followed by positive numbers then n is displaying different output.

Answer (score 1):

Written in C, this seems to work for me.

```
char* str = "-9 1.1 2 3.1 0.9 .8 -2 -1.1";
float n;
int offset;
while (sscanf(str, "%f%n", &n, &offset) > 0) {
  printf("%f,", n);
  str += offset;
}
```

with the output `-9.000000,1.100000,2.000000,3.100000,0.900000,0.800000,-2.000000,-1.100000,`